# EasyApache 4 Frozen on Loading profiles

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, rpm, yum

**Cpanel - Centos 7.8**

**Update**

Running dcrpm provides this error message:

```
2020-07-08 14:21:51,147 ERROR [rpmutil.kill_spinning_rpm_query_processes]: Found                                                         stale rpm process: (7042) /usr/bin/rpm -q --nodigest --nosignature --queryforma
2020-07-08 14:21:51,505 ERROR [dcrpm.run]: DB needs recovery 
2020-07-08 14:21:55,982 WARNING [rpmutil.verify_tables]: Skipping table 'Obsolet                                                        ename', blacklisted
```

yum commands dont return anything and rebuilding the RPM database doesn't seem to change anything.

---

I seem to be having some issues with EasyApache 4 after loading a few PHP extensions on a custom profile. I can no longer load any of the profiles.
I am stuck on an infinite loop of `Loading profiles ...` & when trying to access PHP versions through MultiPHP manager `Gathering PHP-FPM packages information ...` again in an infinite loop. Not quite sure how I've screwed up this time.

All I wanted to do was enable Zip Archives. Is there a way to disable what was enabled without going through there? Or is there a way to remove that profile and the associated enabled extensions?

Apologies I am somewhat of a newbie to all of this so I have come to the community that has helped me endlessly as I learn webdesign and basic code

All I can see in the error log is:

```
*AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/X/public_html/php.ini**
```

---

**More Information**

After leaving it load for an hour or so this appeared:

```
*The YUM cache is incomplete. The system is updating the cache to repair the issue.* 

*This operation can take a few minutes to complete (it is very network and disk i/o intensive). EasyApache 4 will be available as soon as possible ...*
```

The result of which after several hours was:

```
*YUM encountered errors outside of EasyApache 4. Log into the system via SSH to resolve them, or you can click the ‘Refresh’ button to rebuild the system‘s YUM cache.*
```

**Note:** One new plugin was also installed recently (Softaculous) which may have something to do with it as the manage plugin section also doesn't load ._.

**Unfortunately** it seems now that no yum commands are working. I did try to run the following with no result:

```
yum clean all
yum update
```

It appears the proverbial ship is sinking, I can't even access plugins now as i get the follow fatal error:

```
    (XID gvtyx9) The system aborted the subprocess “/bin/rpm” (process ID “23078”) because it reached the timeout of 15 seconds. at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/SafeRun/Object.pm line 546.

Cpanel::SafeRun::Object::die\_if\_error(Cpanel::SafeRun::Object=HASH(0x2a1a970)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/SafeRun/Object.pm line 538

Cpanel::SafeRun::Object::new\_or\_die("Cpanel::SafeRun::Object", "program", "/bin/rpm", "args", ARRAY(0x179bed0), "timeout", 15, "read\_timeout", ...) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/GenSysInfo.pm line 264

Cpanel::GenSysInfo::\_run\_with\_timeout("/bin/rpm", "--query", "--nosignature", "--nodigest", "--queryformat", "%{NAME} %{VERSION}\\\\n", "--file", "/etc/redhat-release") called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/GenSysInfo.pm line 204

Cpanel::GenSysInfo::\_get\_rpm\_distro\_version\_arch() called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/GenSysInfo.pm line 124

Cpanel::GenSysInfo::\_get\_new\_conf(HASH(0x2148000)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/GenSysInfo.pm line 51

Cpanel::GenSysInfo::run() called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/GenSysInfo.pm line 71

Cpanel::GenSysInfo::get\_rpm\_distro\_version() called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Plugins.pm line 181

Cpanel::Plugins::\_do\_url\_variable\_substitution("[http://httpupdate.cpanel.net/cpanel-plugins-c\\$cp\_centos\_major](http://httpupdate.cpanel.net/cpanel-plugins-c\$cp_centos_major)"...) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Plugins.pm line 158

Cpanel::Plugins::get\_baseurls() called at /usr/local/cpanel/Whostmgr/Addons/RPM/Cache.pm line 170

Whostmgr::Addons::RPM::Cache::\_yum\_modules() called at /usr/local/cpanel/Whostmgr/Addons/RPM/Cache.pm line 102

Whostmgr::Addons::RPM::Cache::\_LOAD\_FRESH("Whostmgr::Addons::RPM::Cache") called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/CacheFile.pm line 234

Cpanel::CacheFile::load("Whostmgr::Addons::RPM::Cache") called at /usr/local/cpanel/Whostmgr/Addons/RPM/Cache.pm line 91

Whostmgr::Addons::RPM::Cache::load("Whostmgr::Addons::RPM::Cache") called at /usr/local/cpanel/Whostmgr/Addons/RPM.pm line 62

Whostmgr::Addons::RPM::get\_modules() called at whostmgr/bin/whostmgr2.pl line 2531

main::manage\_plugins("manage\_plugins") called at /usr/local/cpanel/Whostmgr/Dispatch.pm line 274

Whostmgr::Dispatch::\_do\_call("manage\_plugins", HASH(0x2145770), HASH(0x214a890)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Whostmgr/Dispatch.pm line 172

Whostmgr::Dispatch::dispatch("manage\_plugins", 1, ARRAY(0x2147af8), HASH(0x214a890)) called at whostmgr/bin/whostmgr2.pl line 773
```